# CloudSearch simple Range

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to do a very simple range query but it's returning "zero" results. Could anyone check where I am committing a mistake?

"Number_Field" is a INT field, it's suppose to be a date represented by yyyymmdd. I wonder get all documents that was published before 20150906. I am using 2013 CloudSearch API.

Here is what I am trying to do:
    {'q': '(range field=number_field {[,20150906])'}

```
q=%28range+field%3Dnumber_field+%7B%5B%2C20150906%5D%29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your query:

1. You are beginning the range with both the inclusive (`[`) and exclusive (`{`) operators; it should read `{,20150906]` rather than `{[,20150906]`
2. Since your query requires interpretation (rather than being for a literal string to match), you need to be using the structured query parser. I'm not sure what library you're using but you can probably do that by adding `'q.parser': 'structured'` to your array of params.
3. You wrote `Number_Field` as well as `number_field` but keep in mind that field names are case sensitive.

Have a look at [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-ranges.html) for more info.